# Issue training own model using Stanford NLP Regexner feature

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

We have a requirement to extract proper nouns like person, location and organization from unstructured document types (e.g.invoice).

We tried below things:

1. Use Stanford NER classifiers to extract data. The 7 class classifier is giving better results compared to other classifiers, however the accuracy achieved is too less.
2. As recommended, we tried to use caseless classifier for unstructured document type, the accuracy is little higher than earlier, but is still not good enough.
3. We tried to train the model using Stanford NER feature, however that meant training the non noun entities, as others.
4. Therefore, to avoid training non noun entities as others, we decided to train our own data model using Stanford core NLP Regexner feature. However,  some trained entities are tagged as Others. Eg. Italy trained as location is tagged as Others in some cases. Please help.

Sample Input:

```
Sham Ventures
Unit no. 1833, Burj Tower
Plot No. 12 A
Sheikh Zayed Street
P.O.Box 486095
Dubai - U.A.E.
Tel. : +971-4-XXXXXX
Fax : +971-4-XXXXXXX
APPLICATION FOR COLLECTION OF BILLS
DATE: MARCH 14, 2015
TO: TEST BANK 
    DUBAI, UAE
    ATTN: BILLS DEPARTMENT
COLLECTING BANK
DUMMY BANK LIMITED
PLOT 455 Park Avenue Street
P.O.Box 1234
Lagos, Nigeria
TENOR OF DRAFT
60 DAYS FROM B/L DATE MARCH 14, 2015
AMOUNT OF DRAFT
US$90,450.00(US DOLLARS NINETY THOUSAND FOUR HUNDRED FIFTY ONLY)
NAME & ADDRESS OF DRAWER
Sham Ventures
Unit no. 1833, Burj Tower
Plot No. 12 A
Sheikh Zayed Street
P.O.Box 486095
Dubai - U.A.E.
NAME & ADDRESS OF DRAWEE(Buyer)
SUNSHINE MERCANTILE CO LIMITED
PLOT NO. 456 Park Avenue Street
Lagos, Nigeria
PLEASE FOLLOW INSTRUCTIONS MARKED X
DELIVER DOCUMENTS AGAINST PAYMENT ACCEPTANCE
NON-PAYMENT PROTEST NO PRTEST ADVISE BY MAIL ADVISE BY CABLE
INTEREST AT 6% PER ANNUM FROM B/L DATE MARCH 15,2015 to JULY 16, 2015
DO NOT SEND CHASERS FOR NON-ACCEPTANCE OR NON PAYMENT
PLEASE CONTACT AKBAR AT TELEPHONE NO. +971XXXXXXXX FOR INSTRUCTIONS, STAMP & AUTHORISED SIGNATORY(S)
ENQUIRY REGARDING THESE DRAFTS AND OR DOCUMENTS
```

We are expecting following proper nouns to be extracted:
Organization- Sham Ventures,  TEST BANK, DUMMY BANK LIMITED,  SUNSHINE MERCANTILE CO LIMITED

Location- Dubai,  U.A.E, UAE, Lagos, Nigeria

Person- AKBAR

Output extracted using Stanford NER 7 class caseless model is following:

Location- Dubai,  Lagos, Nigeria
Organization- U.A.E, UAE

So, we trained both false positives and false negatives ( following data) to improve the accuracy of entities extraction:

False negatives-

Organization-Sham Ventures,  TEST BANK, DUMMY BANK LIMITED, SUNSHINE MERCANTILE CO LIMITED

Person- AKBAR

False positives-

Location- U.A.E, UAE.

Output after training data-

Person-AKBAR

Organization- DUMMY BANK LIMITED, Sham Ventures,  SUNSHINE MERCANTILE CO LIMITED, TEST BANK

Location-U.A.E, UAE, Lagos, Nigeria, US

Here, Dubai is missing from the results.

Due to such instances, the resultant accuracy for documents with large number of proper nouns  is low

Also we are seeing lot of false positives, for example,

For input,

Yours sincerely
Bosch Packaging Services AG

Output is

Organization- Yours sincerely Bosch Packaging Services AG

Also almost all abbreviations are tagged as Organization using Stanford.

Is there a way out to handle such false positives so that we only get the desired output?

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Arti

Comment: 1. What type of F1 score are you getting in these various cases?  2. What F1 score do you require (are we talking high 90's precision high 90's recall)? 3. Could you show a few small samples of the type of input document you are trying to handle?

Comment: If you want high 90's precision/recall, you are probably going to have to do a lot of careful hand editing of rules.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The type of documents would typically be airway bills, invoice, bill of lading, etc. (OCR scanned). A sample test on 100 mixed kind of these documents gave us around 45% accuracy using Stanford NLP RegexNER trained data feature. (Accuracy % =  (Actual Stanford Retrieved Proper Noun Count / Expected Count of Nouns) *100).  We are aiming to achieve atleast 80% accuracy with trained data. What kind of rules editing is required to improve accuracy? Any help in improving the accuracy is highly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Please note: To check the complete accuracy of Stanford, we have corrected the spell mistakes in the OCR text file.

Comment: You can refer to sample bill documents on the web. If you still need the sample input from our end do let me know. For any other information needed, let me know

Comment: Our NER system is trained on news articles, so that could account for the low recall on your type of data.  It would be helpful if you edited your question and showed an example of the typical text you are processing, because that probably is a big factor.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question and added  sample input data for one of the document types we process using Stanford. The other document types more or less contain same kind of data. Thanks much for your help.

Comment: Team, please help with tips on tweaking the Stanford rules for given document type to improve on the accuracy of the extraction. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: So you say you tried using RegexNer and sometimes Italy is tagged as Other and others it is tagged as LOCATION ?  Could you show the examples where Italy is handled correctly and incorrectly?  Also, how are you calling the pipeline?  Via the command line or in Java code?

Comment: Updated the question with example by considering the same sample input in the question.  We are running this sample input from Java code and not command line. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2265404 Here is the reference code we used to train model using regex, which may help in your investigation. Please do let me know if there is any additional information I need to provide. This is pressing issue for us. Your prompt feedback will help us tons. Thank you team.

Comment: I'll try to provide some more advice soon, I'm looking into an issue...

Comment: Surely,  thanks for the update.